# Rewriting a Javascript equation

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code

```
var total = 5;
var arr = new Array("750", "400", "432", "355", "263");
id = 0;
num = 100;
var ht = 310;
var max = 750;
var cm = 20;
var bHg = 0;
var wdt = 100;
var bm = 20;
for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    ar = parseInt(arr[i]);
    // how to rewrite these equations
    **bHg = (ar * ht / max) / num * id;
    printfu(cm + 50 + (i * (wdt + bm)) + bm,
                cm + (ht - bHg), wdt, bHg);**
}

function printfu(a,b,c,d) {
    document.write(a + b + c + d + "\n");
}
```

From a learning purpose, how can I write the 2 lines with a different equation to produce the same output

```
bHg = (ar * ht / max) / num * id;
printfu(cm + 50 + (i * (wdt + bm)) + bm, cm + (ht - bHg), wdt, bHg);
```

OUTPUT of the above

520 640 760 880 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 lines can be reduced to: `i * k1 + k2` where `k1` and `k2` are constants.

Complete solution:

```
var total = 5;
var arr = new Array("750", "400", "432", "355", "263");
id = 0;
num = 100;
var ht = 310;
var max = 750;
var cm = 20;
var bHg = 0;
var wdt = 100;
var bm = 20;

/*
// It helps to note the bHG is ar times some constant.

var k = ht / max * num * id
var kA = (i * (wdt + bm)) + bm + cm + 50;
var kB = cm + (ht - bHg);
var kC = wdt;
var kD = bHg;

// bHg = ar * k;
var sum = kA + kB + kC + kD;
//=> (i * (wdt + bm)) + bm + cm + 50 + cm + (ht - bHg) + wdt + bHg
//=> (i * (wdt + bm)) + bm + 2*cm + 50 + ht + wdt
*/

var k1 = wdt + bm;
var k2 = bm + 2*cm + 50 + ht + wdt;

for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
   document.write(i * k1 + k2 + "\n");
}

//function printfu(a,b,c,d) {
//    document.write(a + b + c + d + "\n");
//}
```

Comment: This is a rewrite of the first of the learning project: http://jsfiddle.net/SRCXx/1

Comment: @EricFortis cool! I wish I had thought of adding a simplified jsfiddle link :)

Comment: printfu is a placeholder. I have to pass 4 params to the function printfu. How can I do that using your code

Comment: Just a bit more info. Is printfu going to sum the values? or was that just for illustration?

Comment: just for illustration. Actually this code is for plotting a graph but I need to know if there's a way to rewrite the equation I shared in my original code

Answer (score 0):

Well by the look of it, I guess you could precompute some stuff. And if I'm not mistaken, the `printfu` function adds the numbers together? In that case it simplifies to:

```
cm + 50 + i * (wdt + bm) + bm + cm + ht - bHg + wdt + bHg
= 2*cm + i*(wdt + bm) + bm + ht + wdt + 50
```

Since that no longer depends on bHg, you can precompute that too. So just this would work:

```
var pcp = ht * id / max / num,
    pcq = 2*cm + bm + ht + wdt + 50;
for( var i=0;...) {
    bHg = ar * pcp;
    document.write((pcq + i*(wdt+bm))+"\n");
}
```

Comment: and printfu takes 4 parameter, like the one given in my original code..how can i change your logic to fit that scenario and get the same output